# All subgoals have been satisfied, but proof cannot be focused

Tags: coq, coqide

I finished writing a somewhat lengthy proof, but whenever I try `Qed` I get the error message `Error: This proof is focused, but cannot be unfocused this way`. Are there any other ways to unfocus the Proof? Shoudl I just use admitted, even though my proof is rigorous? For reference, I am using CoqIDE 8.6

Comment: Do you mind showing your proof? The [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/proof-handling.html#coq:exn.this-proof-is-focused-but-cannot-be-unfocused-this-way) says that that error is caused by an open `{` that hasn't been closed.

Comment: Where is the reference manual? I would show my proof, but it is the answer for a question in "Software Foundations"

Comment: I linked the exact place where the error is documented in my comment above. For the homepage of the reference manual, see [this link](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/). For a list of possible errors and warnings, see [this link](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/coq-exnindex.html). You may also be interested in the reference manual for Coq 8.6, which can be found at [this page](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.6/refman/).

Answer (score 3):

Solved, I was missing a '}' at the end of my proof.